# NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() throwing Backend sent unrecognized response type: F when try to insert in a table

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am using Npgsql to connect my .Net application to Postgres database. It works well with select queries but when I try to run insert query with parameters, it throwing error.

Comment: Are you sharing this connection between threads? Npgsql isn't thread safe. Sharing the connection is the common source of this problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: Glen Parker gave me a heads up talking about a possibility that you may be facing a bug in old Npgsql versions when handling errors from postgresql 9.3. Which Npgsql version are you using? Which postgresql version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior I find this error while using Npgsql 2.0.11 with PG 9.3.1 through OrmLite. It has been saving other entities just fine, and this one too, but now it started failing. There is a new version of Npgsql, I will try updating.

Comment: Did it work? Try using our latest release as well as our master branch. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it turned out I was inserting duplicate Ids (Id=0).

Comment: In this case, you definitely faced the Npgsql bug when handling error messages from postgresql 9.3. When you tried to insert duplicate ids, Postgresql sent you an error and Npgsql had problems handling the message.